# Tool to diagnose the code to check for errors at runtime

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, code-analysis

Is it possible to check the code and find all places where conversion errors might happen.

for Ex: Wherever = operator is used , i have to check the type of the LHS and RHS variable.

Is it possible with following softwares?

```
submain CodeIt.Right
SSW Code Auditor
```

Comment: Uh, the compiler will do that for you already...

Comment: `Option Strict On` will disallow implicit conversion.

Comment: You say "check the code and find [...] errors that might happen" that isn't runtime, that's compile time... are you looking to debug the code or to find erros during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, turn Option Strict  and Option Explicit On.

Type this at the top of each code file:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
```

Or, in your project settings, you can set it project-wide in the Compile Tab.

Comment: This isn't the only thing you should have on. Make sure that both `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` are both **on**. Then turn **off** `Option Infer`. Don't write code in VB.NET without these set properly.